# FFMPEG: Loop video to the length of audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, mp4, h.264

E.g. if video is 1 minute, but audio is 1 hour. Make video loop throughout for 1 hour of the audio track.

I use this solution to loop image through the lenght of the audio

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -r 6 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But it doesn't work for video, replacing image.jpg with video.mp4 will give error `no loop found`.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55841289/3310334

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For video, stream_loop option should be used.

```
ffmpeg -y -stream_loop -1 -i video -i audio.mp3 -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 50000 -c copy output.mp4
```

You'll have to use a very recent version of ffmpeg (> Nov '17) as stream_loop had a bug, only recently fixed.

Since video encoding is expensive in terms of time and CPU, I've used streamcopy. For most videos, this is fine. Else, you'll have to re-encode.

---

**Edit**: another bug related to stream_loop, see workaround below

```
ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp4 -c copy -v 0 -f nut - | ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 10K -i - -i 1.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest -y out.mp4
```

Comment: Hello. This just strips the audio to the length of video, I meant opposite. Loop video throughout to the length of the audio. For now I'm using solution at https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Use edited command.

Comment: I set the `video` part to video.mp4, video plays until it's original length and stops while audio keeps going, video just stills last frame throughout.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nEcsD7H7 included MediaInfo, as you can see video and audio lengths differ.

Comment: See new command at end

Comment: The first command created an audio-less video of over 44 hours long (from a 3 minute song) before I noticed and stopped it, and the second command craetes an audio-less looping video of the correct length

Comment: the first one loops forever, making infinite video length until I cancel it, the second one puts no audio

Comment: This one works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55841289/3310334

Answer (score 1):

Well, now the default behavior of current/latest ffmpeg via:

```
c:\sbin\ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\video.m4s" -i "\audio.m4s" -c:v copy -c:a copy "D:\combined.mp4"
```

is padding/looping the last frame of the video until `audio.length` === `video.length`.

See if this is acceptable for you.

For details behavior:

- if (`audio.length` < `video.length`), then pad the audio with silent, so that `audio.length === video.length`
- if (`audio.length` > v`ideo.length`), then pad the video with the last frame of this video, so that `audio.length === video.length`